# ¿Cómo actualizar sitios con PUT en bash?

Tags: bash

Quisiera saber como podría crear un bucle para actualizar datos de un sitio web vía `API` con `bash` son mas de 2000 datos así que no seria provechoso actualizarlo uno por uno en este caso estoy actualizando un `ID` (5) que pertenece a otro `ID` (168)

```
#!/bin/bash
# update de sites


url="https://grupobios-test.coupahost.com/api/suppliers/168/supplier_sites/5"
 curl -g -X PUT -d "<supplier-site><code>123</code></supplier-site>" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "X-COUPA-API-KEY:3bce24adf2ef16199c10c6dec2d1980a612f4zz3" -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT " $url
```

Comment: Muchas gracias De hecho ya pude hacerlo leo un csv y envío los datos con CURL y el .sh funciona correctamente ahora quisiera generar un log de errores o tener un mensaje que me indique cuales campos fueron actualizados Muchas gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Podría generar un archivo tipo CSV con los códigos originales y los nuevos, algo así:

```
5;123
6;124
```

Si llamáramos a este archivo `data.csv` podríamos luego, leerlo mediante `bash` y su comando interno [`read`](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=";" read src dst
do
    echo "Actualizando codigo:$src por $dst"
    url="https://grupobios-test.coupahost.com/api/suppliers/168/supplier_sites/$src"
    curl -g -X PUT -d "<supplier-site><code>$dst</code></supplier-site>" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "X-COUPA-API-KEY:3bce24adf2ef16199c10c6dec2d1980a612f4zz3" -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT " $url

done < data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

No entendí bien que es lo que quieres cambiar, pero creo que la idea, que espero dar a entender, se puede adecuar en tu caso.

Voy a tomar la idea de @patricio-moracho del csv.

Puedes crear un archivo llamado `data.txt` con la siguiente estructura.

```
suplier_id,suplier_site_id,suplier_site_code_updated
168,5,123
1,2,3
4,5,6
...
```

Luego puedes crear una función y usar `xargs`.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare DATA_FILE="data.csv"
declare url_base="https://grupobios-test.coupahost.com/api"
export url_base

peticion() {

    declare suplier_id="$1"
    declare suplier_site_id="$2"
    declare suplier_site_code_updated="$3"

    declare url="$url_base/suppliers/$suplier_id/supplier_sites/$suplier_site_id"

    printf "url: %s\nsuplier_site_id: %s\n" \
        "$url" \
        "$suplier_site_code_updated"

    curl -g \
        --request PUT \
        --data "<supplier-site><code>$suplier_site_code_updated</code></supplier-site>" \
        --header "Accept: application/xml" \
        --header "X-COUPA-API-KEY:3bce24adf2ef16199c10c6dec2d1980a612f4zz3" \
        --header "X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT " \
        --url "$url"

}
export -f peticion

xargs --max-args=1 --max-procs=8 -I % bash -c 'peticion $( tr "," " " <<< "%")' < "$DATA_FILE"
```

Para que xargs pueda correr el programa `bash` con la cadena `peticion` como función, es necesario exportar la función `peticion` para que esta pueda ser usada por sub-procesos, lo mismo con la variable `url_base`.

Lo que hace xargs con esos parámetros es correr un máximo de 8 procesos al mismo tiempo que contengan la función `peticion` y que tendrán como parámetro cada registro de `data.csv`. Puedes modificar la cantidad máxima de procesos según las capacidades de la computadora en la que lo corras.

Escribí los paráme tros en su forma verbosa para que sea un poco más claro lo que se pretende dar a entender.

Claramente, la versión 1 lo hace registro por registro, de forma secuencial, la versión 2 puede correr procesos paralelos.

### Actualización.

Esta es una idea muy ineficiente, pero la dejaré por si alguien quiere saber un poco sobre `export` a una función y `xargs` sobre la función exportada.